# kernel busy when pylab is used in ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, chromium, jupyter-notebook

I'm using ipython notebook 1.1.0 (and python 2.7.3) on chromium.
When I use pylab and apply

```
pylab.show()
```

the ipython notebook  freezes with "kernel busy". I've seen that kernel busy is a common bug in ipynb.

After a while on terminal I got:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
```

Any ideas on what to look for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you including "%matplotlib inline" in your code? I had this error, and adding it to my code solved the issue of a hanging kernel.

Check out the official documentation for a more thorough [explanation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/notebook.html#plotting) .

Comment: boris, I don't know why this would be a problem, but it was a good tip, ty

Comment: partially, I used it over again and it worked. Maybe the kernel was jammed or something...

Comment: @b0ris Great find.  Now the plots show up inline.  I love it!